# Ваше устройство взломано злоумышленниками. Немедленно смените пароль!

Tags: centos, ispmanager, exim

Пришло письмо о том, что якобы кто-то там меня взломал и теперь требуют бабло. 
Содержание письма меня не особо интересует, а вот только то, как он отправил с моей почты сайта письмо на эту же почту ? Где искать дыру на сервере ? (на других доменах нет такой фигни)

Comment: Почему Вы думаете, что есть дыра? Протокол SMTP позволяет указать в поле "Отправитель" что угодно.

Comment: Обратный адрес в имейле то же самое, что и на конверте - что захотел, то и написал.

Comment: я в администрировании не совсем грамотен, поэтому и предположил, что невозможно отправить сообщение от имени моей почты не зная пароля от нее.

Answer (score 1):

Пришло аналогичное письмо, вообще не парьтесь, это стандартная e-mail рассылка, еще один спаммер и да, SMTP позволяет написать в "От" кого угодно...

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh, последний кусок ответа (после запятой) - это как раз ответ.

Answer (score 1):

> как он отправил с моей почты сайта письмо на эту же почту?

Установите на другую машину пакет `swaks` (`sudo apt install swaks`) и можете повторить трюк:

```
swaks --body "Вас взломали" --to info@site.ru --from info@site.ru --add-header "Subject: Привет с \"сервера\""
```

> Где искать дыру на сервере ?

Скорее всего ее нет. Если у вас настроена цифровая подпись DKIM, то подложное письмо не пройдет проверку. У яндекса это "красный замочек":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самостоятельно можно проверить через утилиту `dkimverify`.

Также посмотрите заголовки `Received: from`, среди них будет IP злоумышленника.